# Sort List Of Class using Id property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a class called `Questions`. This Questions has properties `QuestionID` and `QuestionAnswer`. My `list of Questions` has QuestionID like 2,3,4,15,12,24,22,,,, etc

I need to sort this List of Questions Object based on QuestionID and store in another `Questions` object.

Comment: How is the list organized? Is it an array of a `List<T>`? Can you supply the actual declaration of `Questions`? From your question it's not clear whether `Questions` represents one single question or that list of questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a framework called LINQ designed for this exact sort of task. For example, in C#:

```
var sortedList = questionList.OrderBy(q => q.QuestionID).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain here how apply desc order?

Comment: @wilo087 Use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`.